# CollapsingToolbarLayout contentScrim is ignored?

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I'm using CollapsingToolbarLayout to show the cover image for an article when it's not collapsed, to do this I use setBackground in my Activity. It used to show the image only when not collapsed and then turn my app primary color after i scrolled a bit but now it just keep showing the image as the toolbar background. Here's my layout(which is basically just the android scrolling activity example layout): https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7c68a84e40568d276fd329370e5224fa
In my code I just call:

```
findViewById(R.id.viewarticle_appbarlayout).setBackground(image);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure why you choose to set the image as a background and on the AppBarLayout. You are using CollapsingToolbarLayout so you can add an ImageView as a child then you can control it's collapse mode. Basically the background and contentScrim is controlled by the the CollapsingToolbarLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/viewarticle_appbarlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/article_collapsingtoolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/article_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/temp_img"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
  </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: I thought you could only have 1 child view in it. Using an image view works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: CollapsingToolbarLayout can have 2 childs (Image + toolbar) but the image must be the first child and it will disappear on collapse.

Answer (score 0):

**CollapsingToolbarLayout** may contain at most two direct childs.

1. View/ViewGroup and
2. Toolbar

If you want to show/hide **View/ViewGroup** during expand/collapse then you should put **View/ViewGroup** as first child and keep **Toolbar** as second child of **CollapsingToolbarLayout**.

Here is an working example:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/layout_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="32dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="16dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="70dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_group_photo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/anim_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <!-- Content -->
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```